# Auto renewable subscription cancel notification : iOS PAYMENT

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

How can we cancel an auto Renewable subscription from itunes and get a call back in our server?After getting cancelled from itunes I should get notified in my server or in phone so that I can call cancel subscription in my server.

I read something like this somewhere

> " When you hit apple server with the last receipt you have saved, it
>   will return you the code for cancellation of subscription"

My doubt is:

Is there any specific error code returned in case if the subscription is cancelled?

I have a cancel button inside my app to cancel subscription.What I think of doing is to redirect to the setting ->manage subscriptions page for now.After cancellation How can I get notified about this?

OR,shall I set a cron in the backend to check for cancellation?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same question: I assumed there would be something like a webhook, notifying me server side of a cancellation. It doesn't make sense to go through all active receipts daily to check who has cancelled. But for cashflow projection reporting it doesn't make sense to find out only that a subscription is cancelled when the subscription is determined to be invalid anymore. (i.e. after it has expired)

Comment: http://savvyapps.com/blog/how-setup-test-auto-renewable-subscription-ios-app Just check this link.Scroll down to :" Subscription Management with Auto-Renewable In-App Purchases"

Comment: @Bjoern 
Can we test ios in app purchase on production?Right now I dont find much useful documentation about this.